# Call I legally receive mail addressed to my roommate that requires a signature?

Tags: criminal-law, contract-law

Say if I share a room or a house and I receive a mail which may need signature because my roommate is out. Is it regarded to be illegal? (the US)

Comment: As long as you give it to your roommate as soon as possible, no, it's not illegal.

Comment: What country/jurisdiction?

Comment: Signing is evidence in favour of the courier or postie that someone at the address was present and received the parcel. It's irrelevant to whether you were permitted to receive the parcel. What you then may, must, may not or must not do with it is a separate question.